# nodeJS cannot find module in the same folder

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, module

I have a simple node application where i want to include a module named dishRouter.
The directory structure is like this :-
[Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqvxU.png)
Dishes/index.js exports the dishRouter that i use in my app.js by
    `var dishRouter = require('/dishRouter')`
When i run app.js using node app, it says : [The Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5OR4T.png)
i tried to print __dirname and it gives
    *"C:\Users\Kush\Desktop\NodeExamples\Express-example\Assignmnet1"*
I do not understand why node cannot find the module 'dishRouter' while it is in the same directory.
Any help is appreciated, and sorry for the messed up structure of questions.
Code in Dishes/index.js :

```js
var DishRouter = require('express').Router();
var fs = require('fs');
var bodyparser= require('body-parser');
DishRouter.use(bodyparser.json());
DishRouter.all('/', function(req,res,next){
  res.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  next();
});
DishRouter.get('/',function(req,res,next){
  res.end('Will send the dish list to you!');
});
DishRouter.post('/',function(req,res,next){
  res.end('will add the Dish named : '+req.body.name+' and the Description : '+req.body.description);
});
DishRouter.delete('/',function(req,res,next){
  res.end('will DELETE all dishes');
});
DishRouter.get('/:dishId',function(req,res,next){
  res.end('Will send the dish with name : '+req.params.dishId+' to you!');
});
DishRouter.put('/:dishId',function(req,res,next){
  res.end('Update the dish named : '+req.params.dishId+', Details to : '+req.body.description);
});
DishRouter.delete('/:dishId',function(req,res,next){
  res.end('will DELETE dish : '+req.params.dishId);
});
module.exports = dishRouter;
```

Code in routes/index.js :

```js
var express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs');
var DishRouter = require('./dishRouter');

var routes= express.Router();
var util = require('util');
routes.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(util.inspect(req));
  res.writeHead(200,{'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  next();
});
routes.delete('/',(req,res)=> {
  res.sendStatus(404);
});
routes.use('/dishes', DishRouter);

module.exports = routes;
```

code in Assignment1/app.js :

```js
var express = require('express');
var routes = require('./routes');
var hostname = 'localhost';
var port = 3000;
var app =express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/routes'));
app.use('/', routes);
app.listen(port,hostname,function(){
  console.log('Server running on port '+port);
});
```

Comment: i do not see dishRouter.js under your routes folder, if you are refering to the sub folder and its index.js you need to change to ./Dishes which is just like the folder name.

Comment: i was confused, does the filename have to be the same as the exporting module?
I thought the module.exports name has to be the same as the one in require('');

Comment: when you module.export you need make sure the export name is the one you created inside the file which is DishRouter,  but when you require you are suppose to use the folder or file name.

Answer (score 1):

In `Dishes/index.js`, the bottom line exports `dishRouter` when you want to export `DishRouter` (capitalization typo).

In `routes/index.js`, you want to use `var DishRouter = require('./Dishes/');` since the exported `DishRouter` is inside the `Dishes` folder.

Comment: Sorry for the Capitalization, i fixed it.
I also changed the require to './Dishes'; now it says it cannot find Dishes module

Comment: @kushshah Try `var DishRouter = require('./Dishes/');` (added a slash at the end of Dishes). `./Dishes` makes node look for a `Dishes.js` file. `./Dishes/` should make it look inside the folder for the `index.js` file.

Comment: I tried it when i tried the first thing you suggested. Same problem, cant find module './Dishes/' .Also, i dont think that is the problem, since i had used require('./routes) somewhere in my application, and routes is a directory, not a JS file, and it worked.

Comment: could it be a problem with the original path which Node uses to search for my modules?

Comment: Can you move `Dishes/index.js` up a folder and rename it `dishes.js`. Then in `routes/index.js` you'd use `var DishRouter = require('./dishes');`

Comment: Perfect!  Worked, thank you...but then, why wont it work inside the folder? 
I tried doing it yesterday  and it worked; it were some changes that i may have made during this time, which caused it to go south.

Comment: I made a trivial example that works. Hopefully this helps.
[https://repl.it/repls/BlueFlashyActivecontent](https://repl.it/repls/BlueFlashyActivecontent)

Comment: Works! Thank you.. but I still need to know why the same approach doesnt work with my code.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `var DishRouter = require('./dishRouter');`,

you must use `var DishRouter = require('./Dishes');`

It doesn't matter what your module exports, what matter is the correct directory path.

Comment: Got it. I changed to require('./Dishes'), now it says, cannot find module Dishes. :/